# Add authorization header to pub sub when doing push subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I created a topic and a subscription for that topic with delivery type "Push" and config so that whenever someone publishes message to my topic it will deliver message to my endpoint by making a POST HTTP Request. To access my endpoint, the request must have Authorization bearer in header. I want to config so that whenever pub sub delivers message to my endpoint (make a POST request) it adds my token to the header.

[image]

I tried to manually publish a message using this feature
[image]

I was able to publish the message and pub sub did deliver message to my endpoint (made a POST request) but it didn't have authorization bearer token in header so it didn't pass my authentication middleware (responded with 401). So the API call was unsuccessful

Comment: Google Cloud does not offer/provide non-expiring tokens. The default expiration for OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens is one hour. With an Org Policy, this can be extended up to 12 hours. Update your question with details.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi Thanks for the reply. Let me explain this more clearly. I have an API in my service. To call that API using postman I need to add my token to Authorization Header. Something like this "Authorization: Bearer {{TOKEN}}" otherwise the respond will be 401. So whenever someone makes an API call to my service it needs to have that token in header. So as PubSub. Push subscription will make a POST API call my service. I checked the logs of my service it shows that pubsub made api calls to my service and it all failed (error 401) because in the header it doesn't have the token.

Comment: In other words all I want to do is add headers when pub sub makes PUSH subscription so that I can add my token in the header

Comment: If your objective is to add an HTTP Authorization Bearer header, then just add the header to the HTTP requests. **Edit** your question and show your code that is making the request, explaining the technical challenges and any error messages. Each language/SDK has its own method of adding headers via its HTTP library. Put those details in your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi I edited the question. Can you take a look? Thanks

Comment: Did you try authenticating as mentioned in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication)?